# Make nginx be able to access all web files when not running as root

Tags: linux, debian, nginx, root

I currently have my server setup as follows

- A new linux user is created for every website
- The websites root folder will be owned by this user and has 700 or 500
- nginx runs as root:root so it can access these files
- nginx passes PHP requests to a PHP-FPM pool for that specific website

Is there any way to not run nginx as root with this kind of setup, I don't know if it can cause any harm that it runs as root, but I'm not entirely comfortable with it.

Thanks, Xeross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to make the www-data group a member of all the groups that had www data.

Answer (score 1):

How about [using ACLs](http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/acl.htm)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't really want to patch my core for this and stuff, how big of a risk is there actually by running nginx as root ?